# How can I decode an integer to datetime?

Tags: datetime, integer, converters

I am trying to convert the integer `77850` to standard date and `4324077` to standard time?

I already tried the OLE automation date converter, the epoch date converter and the unix date converter, but all decode the date as being around the year 2111 , which shouldn't be possible, as I expect the date to be before 2015.

Comment: Well both numbers give you 1970 with a unix date converter, is that not good?

Comment: The question is, where did these number originate?  Is there more than one standard for date and time, depending on which system you're using?

Comment: Thank for reply. Database is convert from firebird to sqlserver, but i found that they used 77850 (int32) to represent date and 432407(int32) represent time, so i need to figure out how these two number come from? :)